# Does RDF store data or does it describe a data model?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, linked-data

I have been working with Linked-Data lately and it has been causing me a headache. Although I have read a lot of pages on the RDF format I dont understand entirely if it is used to hold data, e.g. for a database, or if it is something like a way to model how data interconnect with each other. I apologize if my question is obvious, but I havent been able to clarify this myself.

**An example of a document I came across lately:**

The Europian Commision has about 13485 Skills and Competences listed in their database as described here:  https://ec.europa.eu/esco/portal/skill

However when I download a document with their Skills&Competences from this source https://ec.europa.eu/esco/portal/download I get an RDF document, which doesnt seem to hold 13485 entries. This is how the document looks like:

```
@prefix skos-xl: <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#> .
@prefix dct:   <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> .
@prefix adms:  <http://www.w3.org/ns/adms#> .
@prefix esco:  <http://data.europa.eu/esco/model#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix org:   <http://www.w3.org/ns/org#> .
@prefix iso-thes: <http://purl.org/iso25964/skos-thes#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix skos:  <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix prov:  <http://www.w3.org/ns/prov#> .
@prefix foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .

<http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill/1a4cc54f-1e53-442b-a6d2-1682dc8ef8f9>
        a                       esco:Skill , skos:Concept , esco:MemberConcept ;
        esco:referenceLanguage  "en"^^xsd:language ;
        esco:skillReuseLevel    <http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill-reuse-level/transversal> ;
        esco:skillType          <http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill-type/skill> ;
        dct:description         <http://data.europa.eu/esco/node-literal/7d44a65e-ca7d-4631-a5ce-b33223f383ed> , <http://data.europa.eu/esco/node-literal/059327cb-5ded-4a22-89c5-f0950a69d9d0> ;
        iso-thes:status         "released" ;
        skos:altLabel           "digitale technologieën inzetten voor innovatie"@nl , "twórcze wykorzystanie technologii cyfrowych"@pl , "innovatief gebruikmaken van digitale technologieën"@nl ;
        skos:broader            <http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill/7e5147d1-60b1-4a68-804b-1f5cb0396b91> ;
        skos:broaderTransitive  <http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill/7e5147d1-60b1-4a68-804b-1f5cb0396b91> ;
        skos:inScheme           <http://data.europa.eu/esco/concept-scheme/skill-ict-groups> ;
        skos:prefLabel          "notar stafræna tækni á hugvitsamlegan hátt"@is , "käyttää digitaaliteknologiaa luovasti"@fi , "využívat digitální technologie kreativně"@cs , "kreativno se koristiti digitalnim tehnologijama"@hr , "utilizare creativă a tehnologiilor digitale"@ro , "bruke digitale teknologier kreativt"@no , "använda digital teknik på ett kreativt sätt"@sv , "utilizar de forma criativa as tecnologias digitais"@pt , "radoši izmantot digitālās tehnoloģijas"@lv , "kreatywne wykorzystanie technologii cyfrowych"@pl , "creatief gebruikmaken van digitale technologieën"@nl , "kūrybiškai naudoti skaitmenines technologijas"@lt , "digitale Technologien kreativ einsetzen"@de , "kreativno uporabljati digitalne tehnologije"@sl , "utilizar creativamente las tecnologías digitales"@es , "digitaaltehnoloogiat loovalt kasutama"@et , "anvende digitale teknologier kreativt"@da , "يستخدم بشكل خلاق التكنولوجيات الرقمية"@ar , "teicneolaíochtaí digiteacha a úsáid ar dhóigh chruthaitheach"@ga , "δημιουργική χρήση ψηφιακών τεχνολογιών"@el , "usare le tecnologie digitali in modo creativo"@it , "kreatívan alkalmazza a digitális technológiákat"@hu , "utiliser des technologies numériques de façon créative"@fr , "tvorivo využívať digitálne technológie"@sk , "creatively use digital technologies"@en , "creatively use digital technologies"@en-us , "użu kreattiv tat-teknoloġiji diġitali"@mt , "творческо използване на цифровите технологии"@bg .

<http://data.europa.eu/esco/node-literal/60953fa2-4a4c-45de-b64f-10c475e5674e>
        a                 esco:NodeLiteral ;
        esco:language     "en-us"^^xsd:language ;
        esco:nodeLiteral  "Apply behavioral norms and know-how while using digital technologies and interacting in digital environments. Adapt communication strategies to the specific audience and be aware of cultural and generational diversity in digital environments." .

<http://data.europa.eu/esco/node-literal/02eb4966-46f0-4311-af66-2bbab192c978>
        a                 esco:NodeLiteral ;
        esco:language     "en" ;
        esco:nodeLiteral  "Articulate information needs, search for data, information and content in digital environments, access them and navigate between them. Create and update personal search strategies." .

<http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill/1d6c7de4-350e-4868-a47b-333b4b0d9650>
        a                       esco:Skill , esco:MemberConcept , skos:Concept ;
        esco:referenceLanguage  "en"^^xsd:language ;
        esco:skillReuseLevel    <http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill-reuse-level/transversal> ;
        esco:skillType          <http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill-type/skill> ;
        dct:description         <http://data.europa.eu/esco/node-literal/065e18f8-df44-49a9-a153-25eef949fb07> , <http://data.europa.eu/esco/node-literal/4a925ea1-89a8-4819-94c6-0f2c49e7212e> ;
        iso-thes:status         "released" ;
        skos:altLabel           "gegevens, informatie en digitale content evalueren"@nl , "gegevens, informatie en digitale inhoud beoordelen"@nl , "analizar datos, información y contenido digitales"@es , "evaluar datos, información y contenidos digitales"@es , "izvērtēt datus, informāciju un digitālo saturu"@lv , "gegevens, informatie en digitale content beoordelen"@nl , "examinar datos, información y contenido digitales"@es , "analizează date, informații și conținut digital"@ro , "sonraí, faisnéis agus ábhar digiteach a mheas"@ga , "interpretează date, informații și conținut digital"@ro , "evaluar datos, información y contenido electrónicos"@es ;
        skos:broader            <http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill/629685b8-5f9e-4522-8cff-b3e2c4ec625a> ;
        skos:broaderTransitive  <http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill/629685b8-5f9e-4522-8cff-b3e2c4ec625a> ;
        skos:inScheme           <http://data.europa.eu/esco/concept-scheme/skill-ict-groups> ;
        skos:prefLabel          "evalwazzjoni tad-dejta, tal-informazzjoni u tal-kontenut diġitali"@mt , "evaluate data, information and digital content"@en , "evaluate data, information and digital content"@en-us , "Daten, Informationen und digitale Inhalte bewerten"@de , "αξιολόγηση δεδομένων, πληροφοριών και ψηφιακού περιεχομένου"@el , "evaluează date, informații și conținut digital"@ro , "presojati podatke, informacije in digitalne vsebine"@sl , "analiza danych, informacji i treści cyfrowych"@pl , "оценяване на данни, информация и цифрово съдържание"@bg , "يحدد البيانات والمعلومات والمحتوى الرقمي"@ar , "sonraí, faisnéis agus inneachar digiteach a mheas"@ga , "bedöma data, information och digitalt innehåll"@sv , "gegevens, informatie en digitale inhoud evalueren"@nl , "andmete, teabe ja digitaalset sisu hindama"@et , "valutare dati, informazioni e contenuti digitali"@it , "avaliar dados, informações e conteúdos digitais"@pt , "evaluar datos, información y contenido digitales"@es , "vyhodnocovat údaje, informace a digitální obsah"@cs , "vyhodnocovať údaje, informácie a digitálny obsah"@sk , "adatokat, információkat és digitális tartalmakat értékel"@hu , "arvioida dataa, tietoa ja digitaalista sisältöä"@fi , "evaluere data, informasjon og digitalt innhold"@no , "ocjenjivati podatke, informacije i digitalni sadržaj"@hr , "metur gögn, upplýsingar og stafrænt inntak"@is , "évaluer des données, des informations et des contenus numériques"@fr , "novērtēt datus, informāciju un digitālo saturu"@lv , "evaluere data, oplysninger og digitalt indhold"@da , "vertinti duomenis, informaciją ir skaitmeninį turinį"@lt . [...]
```

I understand that the document is relatively large and that is why I couldnt fit it all here, but it holds predicators and objects for approximately 80 subjects. Does anyone understand what the purpose of this document is? I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: I guess you have downloaded the "Digital Competencies" file only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have been working with Linked-Data lately and it has been causing me
>   a headache. Although I have read a lot of pages on the RDF format I
>   dont understand entirely if it is used to hold data, e.g. for a
>   database, or if it is something like a way to model how data
>   interconnect with each other.

It can be used for either, or both. In the case of the ESCO dataset it holds the actual data, but due to the fact that it is expressed as RDF using particular vocabulary (the `skos:broader` relation is an obvious example) it *also* tells you how the data is interconnected.

> I understand that the document is relatively large and that is why I couldnt fit it all here, but it holds predicators and objects for approximately 80 subjects. Does anyone understand what the purpose of this document is?

The file you're looking at is just a subset of the total set of skills. It's the data for the digital competencies only. The other files available on the site contain the other skills and competencies (with, presumably, the language-based ones making up the bulk of the 13,000+).